# Suggested Edit queue says 0, but I have pending reviews?

Tags: support, editing, review

The suggested edit fools me, **suggests** to me this could be caching. However, the review I have submitted is at least a day old.

Is the caching weekly?

[image: se1]
[image: se2]

Comment: Welcome James!  I think you will likely get a quality answer if you ask this on the main SE Meta site, as your question is not specific to our community.  If you choose to do this, please do link to your question there.  Thanks, and again, welcome!